# Credentials are required to connect to the SQL source

Tags: m, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to get a token from my SQL server. Everytime I run it in VS2017 I'm prompted for credentials. The SQL connection should be made with integrated authentication but the datasource kind of SQL seems like I have a mismatch between what I can enter in the tester and what my code needs to connect.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
[DataSource.Kind="PQExtension1", Publish="PQExtension1.Publish"]
shared PQExtension1.Contents = (optional message as text) =>
    let
        _message = if (message <> null) then message else "(no message)",
        a = "Hello from PQExtension1: " & getToken()
    in
        a;



getToken = () =>
    let
        t = Sql.Database("sqlserver", "accounting", [Query="EXEC GetToken"]),

        token = Table.FirstValue(t)
    in 
        token;



PQExtension1 = [
    Authentication = [
        Implicit = []
    ],
    Label = Extension.LoadString("DataSourceLabel"),
    SupportsEncryption = false
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this answer on another forum

> As of today, a builtin connector generally needs to be
>   "extensibility-enabled" to serve as the basis for a custom data
>   source. The SQL connector does not enable extensibility in this
>   fashion. Using the SQL Server ODBC driver instead should work for you.
>
> In this case, if the SQL connector were extensibility-enabled, you'd
>   need to pick Windows authentication instead of "Implicit".